# Http to Https htaccess Redirect Breaks SSL Security

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have the following .htaccess file that redirects HTTP pages to HTTPS, which is DOES do -- however, it breaks security in Firefox and IE. It has *something* to do with the #FORCE HTTP section of the code, because when I remove that section, and just keep the #FORCE HTTPS section, security works fine in all browsers.

I can tell something is happening because while the page is loading, it shows the verified lock symbol for a split second but then it disappears entirely. I mean entirely; it does not even show the broken lock icon.

Note that the url is still https:// when it does this. So even if I type in https:// manually it does this.

```
# FORCE HTTP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/(donate|debit)/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|gif|etc|jpeg) [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/(donate|debit)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: If you capture the HTTP traffic e.g. using Fiddler, are there any 301 redirects and if so for which resources?

Comment: What happens if you just comment out: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|gif|etc|jpeg) [NC]
 I wonder if insecure resources are being loaded on a secure page, that may cause the problem. Also in your html, do you have any <base> tag in the header?

Comment: I don't see any 301's in Fiddler. Everything is HTTPS or HTTP Tunneling via 443. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|gif|etc|jpeg) [NC]` code protects an HTTPS page from having it's resources changed to HTTP.

Comment: I know the HTTP section of redirects is the culprit, however... just don't know where or how.

Comment: If, in a secure page, you load javascript, css, or images from a unsecure (http) connection, browsers will remove the padlock. That is because not all traffic is secure and information could leak. My guess is that you have some `.jpg` file that doesn't match your rule, because it only matches `.jpeg` files.

Comment: Changing that line to this has no effect: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|gif|etc|jpeg) [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

write ( Remember `L` )

```
# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$ - [NC,L]
```

before #FORCE HTTP